# Statistics not collected on Insert-Select

Tags: oracle, optimization, statistics, bulk-insert

Based on the information [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/online-statistics-gathering-for-bulk-loads-12cr1), I expected the statistics to be automatically collected during an Insert-Select operation on a new table in Oracle. However, I don't see any table-level statistics gathered after an insert-select operation.

I have set the parameter ***_optimizer_gather_stats_on_load*** to *TRUE*.

As per requirement (this only works for new tables), I created a new table. There are no rows prior to insert-select and 500 rows post insert-select operation.

Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This only works with direct path loads: `INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO ... SELECT ...`.

It does not apply to conventional path insert (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, without `/*+ APPEND */` hint).

This is also explained on the site behind the link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with /*+ APPEND */ hint and still statistics are still not updated.

Comment: @Darzen Then we need to know what exactly you tried to do. For all we know, you could have used a built-in schema such as `SYS`, but this feature does not work on tables in that schema.